# NewStringUTF() and freeing memory

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Should I free the allocated string after passing it to `NewStringUTF()`?

I have some code similar to:

```c
char* test;
jstring j_test;

test = some_function(); // <- malloc()s the memory
j_test = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, test);

free(test); // <- should this be here?
```

When I free the string after passing it to `NewStringUTF()`, I get a `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad` error. If I remove the `free()` call, the error vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

I see conflicting opinions. Some say I should free it myself, some say the VM frees it, some say the VM doesn't free it and you should do strange voodoo magic to free it. I'm confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNI Freeing Memory to Avoid Memory Leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533378/jni-freeing-memory-to-avoid-memory-leak)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The storage for the `const char*` argument to `NewStringUTF()` is entirely your responsibility: if you allocated `test` with `malloc()`, then you need to `free()` it.  So, the snippet you posted is correct. You are corrupting the heap somewhere else.

> I see conflicting opinions. Some say I
>   should free it myself, some say the VM
>   frees it, some say the VM doesn't free
>   it and you should do strange voodoo
>   magic to free it. I'm confused.

They are talking about the `jstring` instance returned by `NewStringUTF()`. That follows the confusing rules for ['local references'](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local).

It is never an error to release this reference with `DeleteLocalRef()` when you are finished with it.  However, the JVM performs some dubious magic if you call `NewStringUTF()` in the context of a JVM thread.  When the native method returns to Java, any leaked local references are automatically cleaned up. So if you are sure your ultimate caller is in a Java thread, then you can safely leak the reference.

On the other hand, if you are running in the context of a native thread - say, some event reporting thread making callbacks to Java - there never is a return to Java, so you must call `DeleteLocalRef()` yourself on this `jstring` (and indeed all the other local references returned by typical JNI calls).

Comment: Interersting. I now know where my ploblem is. I need a more persistent jstring. One which becomes part of the garbage collector and is only cleaned once I am truly done with.

Comment: Is there ever a situation where it's unsafe/incorrect to call `DeleteLocalRef()` on a `jstring` obtained with `NewStringUTF()`?

Comment: @namuol if you are passing jstring to java later, you should never delete it now.

Comment: side note: jni's entry to save local reference is limited, so it's good to delete local reference as soon as you don't need it. Imagine, following code will cause a crash `for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {callToJava(NewStringUTF(...)})`, jni will complain about too many local reference.

Comment: Push/PopLocalFrame is your friend here, especially when using non-JVM threads.  It handles the allocation of sufficient local reference space as well as automatically cleaning up whatever local references are still dangling.

Comment: @namuol I've just had serious issues with calling DeleteLocalRef() after using the jstring in a callback to Java (on Android). If I remove the deletes and let the JVM handle them, all is good. If I have them in, I get a crash on the next call to the Java callback. Very, very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

You just need `DeleteLocalRef()`, `NewStringUTF()` is just `malloc` memory on JVM, which the JVM will take care of the memory.