# How to get sent string from java code to native C in Android

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on android app in which I am using NDK for a small stuff. How to get sent string from java code to native C. I want to get a value in native C code which was sent from java code.

Here is my code which I wrote in activity

```
observer("test@gmail.com");
public native void observer(String email);
```

And Native code is this

```
void
Java_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity_observer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    // I want to get email.. How to get
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The signature looks wrong, did you use javah to generate it?

Comment: No, what would be the signature of native c method when I am passing email in it  and how to access it in native code ?

Comment: OK, I've changed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use [javah](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) to generate the headers so you don't have any mistakes. Also recommend sticking it in a batch file so you can update with ease.

From source folder:

```
...\src> javah pl.pelotasplus.actionafteruninstall.MainActivity
```

Will generate the following .h file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity */

#ifndef _Included_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity
#define _Included_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity
 * Method:    observer
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity_observer
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Note the header does not include names for the parameters, so add them when implementing like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity_observer
      (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring email){

   const char *nativeEmailString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, email, 0);

   // use your string

   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, email, nativeEmailString);
}
```

Comment: how to use either *nativeEmailString or nativeEmailString ?

Comment: What do you mean "how to use"? It's a native c string at that point, so do whatever you want

Comment: The problem with `GetStringUTFChars` is that it produces _Modified_ UTF-8, something which the native code might not be able to use correctly—after all it was invented for JNI. (Note: for many strings, modified UTF-8 and UTF-8 are the same. If all strings will be, throw an exception when they turn out not to be.) If you really want to convert any Java string to UTF-8, use String.getBytes.

Comment: @TomBlodget interesting, do you have any links that explain the "modified" nature of the UTF-8 results of `GetStringUTFChars`?

Comment: There is the canonical book _The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification_ by Sheng Liang (Sun) and Orcale [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#modified_utf_8_strings) and Andriod [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 void Java_pl_pelotasplus_actionafteruninstall_MainActivity_observer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring jstr) {
    char* email = jstringToCharArray(env, jstr);
}
```

jstringToCharArray:

```
    char* jstringToCharArray(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr)
{

    char* rtn = NULL;
    jclass clsstring = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jstring strencode = env->NewStringUTF("utf-8");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clsstring, "getBytes", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
    jbyteArray barr= (jbyteArray)env->CallObjectMethod(jstr, mid, strencode);
    jsize alen = env->GetArrayLength(barr);
    jbyte* ba = env->GetByteArrayElements(barr, JNI_FALSE);
    if (alen > 0)
    {
    rtn = (char*)malloc(alen + 1);

    memcpy(rtn, ba, alen);
    rtn[alen] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: A lot of problems with this code. No `free()` on email, no `ReleaseByteArrayElements` on `ba`. The `NewStringUTF` and `FindClass` could have a `DeleteLocalRef` incase this is used from a [native thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238785/newstringutf-and-freeing-memory)