# Difference between '\0' and 0 for terminate the string

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using JNI code for generate random string and return it to back to calling function using below code.

```
static const char alphanum[] =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

  jstring Utils::getRandomString(JNIEnv *env, const int len) {

        char s[len + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            int p = rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
            s[i] = alphanum[p];
        }
        s[len] = 0;
        return env->NewStringUTF(s);
    }
```

i am confused about how to terminate the string in JNI,i have seen there are two way

```
s[len] = 0;
```

AND

```
s[len] = '\0'
```

can anyone explain what is difference between both? and which one is right for JNI code?reason for identifying this thing is application is crashing on some device after adding  `s[len] = '\0'` when it's   `s[len] = 0;` it's working fine.
I am not able to generate this crash but it's reported on fabric console http://crashes.to/s/2e4bca9a62c .

Comment: Both should be identical. `\0` add more type information.

Comment: @Jarod42 as per my analysis after updating s[len] = 0; to s[len] = '\0' crashes are reported

Comment: _"as per my analysis after updating s[len] = 0; to s[len] = '\0' crashes are reported"_ That seems extremely unlikely. You should look for other possibilities.

Comment: Since this appears to be C++, why aren't you using `std::string`? For that matter, you may want to use [a better PRNG](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

Your question and problem are unrelated - let me answer your problem...
Your crash is because NewStringUTF does not copy it's argument; it is your responsibility to keep the memory valid for the duration of the life of the java string.

You however provide a local variable as the pointer, which leaves scope; leaving access to it as undefined behavior.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238785/newstringutf-and-freeing-memory

Comment: @UKMoney here is crash report http://crashes.to/s/2e4bca9a62c,can you please help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: _"Your crash is because `NewStringUTF` does not copy it's argument; it is your responsibility to keep the memory valid for the duration of the life of the java string."_ Java strings use UTF-16 encoding, so by necessity `NewStringUTF` will convert the UTF-8 data you provide into UTF-16 and store it in some newly allocated memory. It's perfectly fine to free the memory that held the original UTF-8 string as soon as `NewStringUTF` returns.

Comment: ART can do string "compression" in some cases, which doesn't trigger a conversion. But it still copies the string data.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain what is difference between both?

In the assignment in:

```
s[len] = '\0';
```

`'\0'` is a `char` *literal constant*.

and in the assignment:

```
s[len] = 0;
```

`0` is an `int` *literal constant*. Since this `int` is being assigned to a `char`, it gets *converted* to `char` (`s` is declared as `char s[len + 1]`). The result of that conversion has the same value as `'\0'`. That is, after that assignment, evaluating the condition:

```
s[len] == '\0'
```

yields true.

In that context it doesn't matter which one you use, but I would recommend you to stick to the form `s[len] = '\0'` to explicitly indicate that is a `char` what is being assigned to.

Comment: isn't 0, when seen as char, '\0'?

Comment: @isaac, int 0, when seen as char, is rather '\0\0\0\0' on most of modern architectures due to the actual size of the corresponding types.  
But conversation to char cuts higher bytes. And it the current context it should happen on compile time.