# JNI: Is it safe to make java object a C++ class member?

Tags: java, memory-management, java-native-interface

My question coincides with **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533378/jni-freeing-memory-to-avoid-memory-leak)**, but there are no details there on my specific question.
I can't understand one thing, I didn't find in the spec, and I'm quite surprised no one asked it. 
Consider the operator:

```
m_str = m_env->NewStringUTF("string");
```

How are references to Java objects created from C++ counted? May those objects be stored across native (C++) methods calls, or they will be collected once С++ method finishes execution and returns control to Java?

Comment: Your question coincides with which one?  I don't see any link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as long as you use `NewGlobalRef` to convert the local reference to a global one before storing the Java object reference as a member of your C++ class.

After having converted the local reference to a global one, call `DeleteLocalRef`.

Finally, as part of your C++ destructor, make sure you call `DeleteGlobalRef` on the reference to the member Java object.

Your C++ class's copy constructor has to call `NewGlobalRef` too.

See [Local and Global References](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've read some docs and part of JNI spec, but I have overlooked this particular section.